# Java: Why do I keep getting a StringIndexOutOfBoundsException for this method?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, encode

I have written a static method that is intended to take a string and scramble it.

When you input a given string, such as "four score and seven", you are supposed to get the output

"f rneosedvuc  eroasn", because the String is scrambled into the grid below.

```
row 1:       f   r n e

row 2:       o s e d v

row 3:       u c     e

row 4:       r o a s n
```

When I run this method, I keep getting the `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` at lines that use `s.charAt(i)`. I am not sure why this is. No matter how much I change the for loop test, which clearly seems to be the problem, I still get this error.

Code:

```
public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println(encode("four score and seven", 4));
}
public static String encode(String s, int n){
    String finalOutput = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        String output = "";
        for(int j = 0; j < s.length() - 1; i += n){
            System.out.println(s.charAt(i) + " " + i);
            output += s.charAt(i);
        }
        finalOutput += output;
    }
        return finalOutput;
    }
}
```

Comment: for(int j = 0; j < s.length() - 1; i += n){ how come i += n is here?

Comment: I am attempting to add the char that is at the index i, then i + n, then i + n. The letters are n away from each other in index.

Comment: If length is 5 then i would reach 12 which is clearly out of bounds. Also, since you never increment j, your loop runs forever.

Comment: length is 5 for what? I am not sure what you are suggesting. The length of the test string is 20.

Comment: Oh wait. I understand now!

Comment: It was just an example. If the length is 20 then `i` will eventually reach 76. It doesn't though because it goes out of bounds well before this. And again, even if you fix this you will eventually get out of bounds because your for loop runs forever. Since `j` never increases it will always be `< 20`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The condition must be like that:

```
for(int j = 0; j < (s.length()-1) && i<s.length(); j++, i+=n)
```

U havent incremantation j++, but your loop is going to infinity.

Comment: even when I converted s.length to s.lenght() ,and I add to my code. my code gives me **Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous tree type: <any>
 at Test.encode(Test.java:19)
 at Test.main(Test.java:13)
Java Result: 1**

Comment: Oh sorry ^^ I forgot about that.

Answer (score 0):

just change

```
for(int j = 0; j < s.length() - 1; i += n) to <br />
for(int j = 0; j < s.length() - 1 &amp;&amp; i&lt;s.length(); i += n)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the second loop u should initial with j = i ,it will make your code simple

```
String finalOutput = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            String output = "";
            for (int j = i; j < s.length() ; j += n) {
                System.out.println(s.charAt(j) + " " + j);
                output += s.charAt(j);
            }
            finalOutput += output;          
        }
        return finalOutput;
```